# Arc length of f(x)=1/2(x^2) between o and p.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

this should be a really simple question but I've now been trying for hours and hours - I may just be particularly bad at this, so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Let $\ f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$. I want to calculate the definite integral:

$$\int_0^p \left(1+f'(x)^2\right)^{1/2} dx$$

Since $\ f'(x)=x$, the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^p (1+x^2)^{1/2} dx$$

I am also given the hint that $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^t-e^{-t}\right)$, so I naturally try to go for integration by substitutions.

$$\int_0^p \left[1+(e^t-e^{-t})^2\right]^{1/2} \cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right) dt$$

From this point on, I've tried to expand the parentheses in every direction to see if something magical happened but it just gets incredibly messy.

**Ideally, I want a non-trigonometric answer.** WolframAlpha can't solve the problem even with extended time and when I break it down, I get answers in terms of $\sinh(x)$.

Now, I'm desperate for a nudge in the right direction.

**UPDATE.**
Thanks for all your feedback and hints. Here's how I've tried to use it so far:

First of all, I made a typo when I typed in the integral above, as you pointed out. It looks like this:

$$\int_0^\rho \sqrt{1+\left[\frac{1}{2}(e^t-e^{-t}\right]^2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right) dt$$

I also changed the upper limit from *p* to $\rho$ (see below). Rory Daulton added that "There is one more sticking point", and I think this might be it. I then expand the term inside the square root, collect it, and I get:

$$\int_0^\rho \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left[2+e^{2t}-e^{-2t}\right]}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right) dt$$

and since $(e^t+e^{-t})^2=2+e^{2t}-e^{-2t}$ (Is this the "convenient cancellation"?), I can substitute this into the integral and take the square root (although it was recommended that I use: $a^{1/2}⋅b=(a⋅b^2)^{1/2}$, but I must have missed something, because surely I should take the square root?)

$$\int_0^\rho \frac{1}{2}\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(e^t+e^{-t}\right) dt=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\rho \left(e^t+e^{-t}\right)^2 dt$$

which is

$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{e^{2t}}{2}-\frac{e^{-2t}}{2}+2t\right]_0^\rho$$

The lower limit was before the substitution $x=0$. Now, it is: $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^t-e^{-t}\right)=0 \to t=0$. The upper limit, on the other hand, seems like a nightmare (and I tried Wolfram Alpha for help and saw the $\sinh$ function pop up a lot - and you are right, I have absolutely no idea what it is. My course doesn't involve trigonometry and I don't even recall it from high school).

$$\ln\left(e^t-e^{-t}\right)=\ln(2p)$$

which, according to Wolfram Alpha, is $\ln(2 \sinh(t))=\ln(2p)$ so I just assume I can get rid of the logarithms:

$$\sinh(t)=p$$

which I can't solve. Instead of chasing this solution, I guess I should wrap my head around the trigonometric solution.

Comment: You have a mistake in the square parantheses. It is 1 + 1/4 *(e^t-e^(-t))^2 = (e^t+e^-t)^2 and so when you take the root and multiply you will get (e^t + e^-t)^2

Answer (score 1):

Hints;

For simplicity's sake, solve the indefinite integral $$\int \sqrt{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

Let $u=\tan(x)$ then get $$\int \sec^3(u) \mathrm{d}u$$

Remember the reduction formula $$\int \sec^m (x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sin(x)+\sec^{m-1}(x)}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int \sec^{m-2}(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Them multiply and divide the integrand by $\tan (u)+\sec (u)$ and substitute $t=\tan (u)+\sec (u)$

It's easy from here, use the fundamental theorem of calculus on your end result for your $_0^p$ bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do now know what $\text{sinh}(x)$ means? If you did, the problem would become easier. But it is not strictly necessary.

In your last integral, you left out the $\frac 12$ in the substitution for $x^2$. If you put that in and expand the $[\frac12(e^t-e^{-t})]^2$, you get some convenient cancellations.

Also, don't "expand" the second parentheses, instead use the identity

$$a^{1/2} \cdot b = (a \cdot b^2)^{1/2}$$

Keep going at it, and the answer should come. There is one more sticking point: ask if you need to when you get there. This is the point that is easier if you understand and use $\text{sinh}(x)$.

---

**ADDED:**

As UserX shows in his answer, the trigonometric solution is more straightforward in many ways, so use that if you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Arc Length

$$\int \sqrt{\left( (\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dx}{dt})^2\right)}dt$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{4} (e^{2t} - e^{-2t}) = \frac{1}{2} sinh\ 2t$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}(e^{t} + e^{-t}) = cosh\ t$$

$$ \int \sqrt{\left( {\frac{1}{4} sinh^{2}\ 2t} + {cosh^{2}\ t}\right)}dt$$

Worlfram spits out answer immediately.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int+%28\sqrt%28%28sinh%282t%29%2F2%29^2+%2B+%28cosh%28t%29%29^2%29dt

Comment: Hi, this is great, but I'm not at all familiar with trigonometry so I'll have to digest this for a bit.